# number to percentage exception handler that makes NaN into 0%

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a line of code that essentially calculates the conversion rate. However if it's a new campaign, the conversion rate will be displayed as NaN%, instead of 0.00% (I have precision of 2).

I tried adding

```
rescue 0.00
```

at the end however it had no success. Here's my code snippet:

```
number_to_percentage((campaign.favorites.where(:owner_id => current_user.followers.map(&:follower_id)).count.to_f / campaign.favorites.where(favorited: true).count.to_f * 100), precision: 2) rescue 0.00
```

Any clue on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can just use an `if` condition instead of rescue, or just raise an exception if the `percent` value is equal to 0.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fav = campaign.favorites.where(favorited: true)
val = fav.present? ? campaign.favorites.where(:owner_id => current_user.followers.map(&:follower_id)).count.to_f / fav.count.to_f) : 0.0

number_to_percentage(val)
```

Comment: how do I implement this in the Campaign model, I get an undefined method on 'current_user.followers' which I changed to 'User.followers'?